# How to align local coordinate with global axis?

Tags: modeling, transforms, coordinates

I want to know if there is a way to align the local axis of an object to its global axis, without actually rotating the object. Please help me out, thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to bring up the Apply object Transformation menu and select **Rotation**.

[image]

From the [blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply#apply-object-transformations):

> This will make Blender consider the current rotation to be equivalent to 0 degrees in each plane i.e. the selection will not rotated, the current rotation will be considered to be the “default rotation”

Answer (score 1):

If you have the object selected in *Object Mode* then press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> , it resets the local rotations to the global rotations without manually rotating.

Comment: You should use the description of the function rather than the shortcut. What is `Ctrl R` in your case? None of the [current shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wYIK.png) is related to resetting the orientation.